# How to increase the cpu utilisation of a process in windows 8

Tags: windows, process, cpu-usage

I am doing a project for my college using WEKA, I am classifying a very large text file(300MB). But it is a very slow process.

I looked in the task manager and I saw that weka uses only 10% of the cpu, and overall cpu utilization is around 13%. I want to increase weka's cpu utilsation. I already set the priority of weka as 'high'.

Any ideas how can I do that?
[image]

Comment: How many processors do you have and how many threads does your app use?

Comment: Unless you are going to edit the source files, this questiona is probably better suited for http://superuser.com.

Comment: If you are running this on a 4GB system, try it on an 8 or 16 GB system and tell us the results along with total memory on system

Comment: My laptop has intel i3 processor(2.1GHz) with 6GB Ram, and as I said I am using WEKA so I don'e have control on threads and all.

Comment: I changed the process priority from high to real time and now there are occasional spike...from 10 to 20 to 30 to 9 etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are training (train data set), weka uses 10-fold cross validation by default. Weka Explorer or command line does all folds in single thread. It is possible to execute each fold on thread separately by using GUI Weka KnowledgeFlow. This would be the easiest way in you case. However, each folds can be distributed to others computer so the each fold can be executed on different machine. For more information about fold distribution see [Weka-Parallel](http://weka-parallel.sourceforge.net/).